# What are the regular checkups needed on a SharePoint installation?

Tags: 2007, maintenance

What are the regular check ups that need to be done on a SharePoint installation to preemptively prevent any problems or at least detect them early?

I can think of:

- Checking event logs
- Check SharePoint logs
- Checking That databases backups are done regularly

What else needs to be done and how often?

Comment: for more discussion-like questions like this, you should consider marking question community-wiki

Comment: @Emad: As Anders suggests, this should be commmunity wiki as it is a list of resources. Please see http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/432/what-does-community-wiki-mean for more info about why. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theres a good planning guidance for this on TechNet: [Plan for site maintenance and management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262509.aspx)

- Ask users what they want in
  IT-managed sites. Perform periodic
  surveys to determine what your users
  need from the site.
- Use usage logs and reports to find
  out which areas of the site are being
  used, and then correlate that with
  user surveys to find out what can be
  improved.
- Archive obsolete content or sites.
  However, if you are going to archive
  or delete obsolete content or sites,
  be sure that users understand that
  plan, and that you perform these
  actions only at predictable times.
  For example, publish a schedule of
  when you are going to archive content
  or delete unused sites.
- Periodically review site permissions.
  For example, review the permissions
  quarterly to remove permissions for
  any users who have left the group or
  project.
- Select a reasonable time interval for
  your maintenance activities. For
  example, if you plan to conduct
  periodic user surveys, do not conduct
  them more than twice a year (and
  preferably, no more than once a
  year).
- Create a plan for regular backups of
  site content. Determine or discover
  how often backups will be made, and
  the process for restoring content
  when necessary. For more information
  about planning for backup and
  restore, see Plan for data protection
  and recovery (Office SharePoint
  Server).

Answer (score 8):

Here's a checklist I use when going into a new client to do a 'Health-Check' of their systems before starting on anything.

[alt text http://pv3kcq.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pXgiTCmoDE6_A1KkqU9saAYzwmh5n0F9K7k5aOAieL-xFFc9TA4ENn03WJtQUOwHAymZ7MAWcKccwtbw8IfKXKOQ81j97ZX-1/SharePoint_Health_Check.png](http://pv3kcq.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pXgiTCmoDE6_A1KkqU9saAYzwmh5n0F9K7k5aOAieL-xFFc9TA4ENn03WJtQUOwHAymZ7MAWcKccwtbw8IfKXKOQ81j97ZX-1/SharePoint_Health_Check.png)

Answer (score 7):

If you've got MS Premier Support then ask about a MOSS RAP (Risk Assesment Program), they have some good diagnostic tools and you are licensed to use them for 12 months after the RAP takes place.  They will also recommend you a decent maintenance plan which will be ideal for the size of your environments.

Keep a close eye on your search crawls.  When are your full and incrementals taking place?  How long are they taking.

Also monitor the IO peformance of your indexing and SQL servers as both can be heavily impacted during search indexing.

Answer (score 4):

Automated monitoring is a good start. Operations Manager has some [great management packs](http://blogs.technet.com/keithcombs/archive/2007/06/17/microsoft-office-sharepoint-server-2007-management-pack-for-operations-manager-2007.aspx) for both WSS and MOSS.

Additionally, it's well worth taking a squiz at the output from the Microsoft [Best Practices Analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263211.aspx) from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have properly [configured diagnostic logs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288649.aspx) and check for possible errors in these logs on regular basis.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your content databases do not go over 50-100GB. Check [SharePoint Collection Governance](http://www.intranetjournal.com/articles/200804/ij%5F04%5F07%5F08a.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing i can highly recommend is to do a performance baseline check for your solution before you start installing any custom code or third party products, for both your test/integration servers and preprod/prod environments.

After each deploy you do another benchmark and compare it to your baseline.

This will help you **alot** when you start developing functionality that, inevitably, will slow down your system. That way you can catch "bad deploys" very early.

Theres different approaches and tools for this. [Stress test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292187%28VS.71%29.aspx) in Visual Studio Test Edition is one way, but a simple load test tool like [WCAT](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/aff5a41e-26b2-4338-b062-7649a9e14e16.mspx) or similar could also give a good indication of degrading performance that hints that a badly performing assembly was deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all SharePoint services are running, and that proper privileges are set (e.g. Search content access account has proper privileges)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned checking the event logs.  I'm not sure about the others, but I don't have time to log into each server to check events lots, disk space, etc so I always insist on some form of a monitoring system that can do that for me.  It makes it easy to setup rules so that you know what is important and can take quick action.

With regards to Disk Space, make sure your diagnostic logging is configured so that you have the detail you need without giant log files.  Break them into smaller time intervals if needed, and make sure that an appropriate number are saved.  I have seen servers with over 10GB of log files up to the point where the server stops working.

Comment: Agreed. Managing the amount of space taken up by logging while simultaneously keeping an appropriate amount data to diagnose past events is often overlooked. We've setup scheduled powershell scripts to compress and store log files off on a cheaper network storage medium.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned the number one check I make as soon as possible when taking over a SharePoint installation, check the restore plan. Checking backups is only useful if you know that you can restore them. Restoring your backups on a regular basis is the only way to check that they are sufficient when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much related to the question you already asked [What are the maintenance actions that can be done on a SharePoint application to ensure optimum performance?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1040/what-are-the-maintenance-actions-that-can-be-done-on-a-sharepoint-application-to) 
In other words make sure you maintain your SQL server which is the heart of your SharePoint solution.

Comment: The first questions was about automatic tasks to be set initially. This one is about regular manual system checkup.