# Sharepoint loades pages and data views very slow

Tags: 2013

The sites load slow and especially the data views are loading very slow.

I followed "[Sharepoint 2010 - How can I speed up the Site Performance?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58305/how-can-i-speed-up-the-site-performance/58925#58925)" but it didn't work for me.

What else should I do?

**Edited:**

It's an intranet. There is one site collection with one web app but it includes a lot of subsites. There is over 1000 users.

Data views are get the datas from another server. But loading the pages ,that includes data view, takes at least 4-5 seconds. One page includes one data view with 1500 rows, not multiple data views. When I try to filter it or go to next page of data view it takes at least 6 seconds. I check the times from the slowest page at central administration.

Other pages that don't include any data view, loads pages slow too but when they refresh, it loads not slow. But a data view page loads always slow.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your farm setup and topology?  Also, is it a first time slowness or is it always slow no matter how many times you load the page?

Comment: What is your farm topology?  How many WFEs, app servers, SQL servers, etc?  This data the loads from another server, is that through a direct sql call or webservices?

Comment: One app server (SP 2013) and one SQL server 2012. Yes, direct sql call.

Comment: Enabling the Developer Dashboard (http://sps2013.blogspot.com/2012/07/developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-2013.html) should help you identify where the bottleneck is.

Comment: So no web front end servers or do you just have one sharepoint server that does all of the roles except for SQL?  When you execute the sql command using sql management studio, how long that that sql command take?

Comment: Thanks Dave. It shows me that SPSqlClient and ScriptLink Control Render is the problem. I'll search why they are the problem. Maybe the reason is reaching the data from one server to another one.